# VBA Two for Loop and Collect the value to second sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get this subroutine working .

I have data in one sheet(ws1) through which i would loop and copy the data if the values are not 0 to sheet(ws).Range("E5").end(xldown).offset(1,0)

Please help

---

```
 Sub Test()

 Dim r As Integer
 Dim c As Integer
 Dim amount As Long
 Dim account As Variant
 Dim Acct As Range
 Dim Amt As Range
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet
 Dim target As Range
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws1 = ActiveSheet 
 Set ws = Worksheets("Updated")
 Set target = ws.Range("E5:E" & Range("E5").End(xlDown)).Select

   ws1.Activate

  Range("A8").Select

   For r = 8 To ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Row

  Cells(r, 1).Select
  account = ActiveCell.Value

   For c = 2 To ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select        
    amount = ActiveCell.Value

   If ActiveCell.Value <> 0 Then

    target.Offset(1, 0).Value = amount       
    target.Range("E5").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1) = account

    End If

     Next     
       Next

     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    End Sub
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I want to get Amount and Account variable value copied to sheet ws as it loops through all values the sheet ws should get those values one after another

Comment: Amount first followed by account?

Comment: Yes , on the second sheet Amount goes to Range("E6") and continuous down on ext amount

Comment: Account goes to Range("E6").offset(0,1) and continuous on next account loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()

Dim source As Worksheet, target As Worksheet, rng As Range, col As Integer, account As Range

Set source = ActiveSheet
Set target = Worksheets("Updated")

For Each rng In source.Range("A8:A" & Range("A8").End(xlDown).Row)

    Set account = rng

    For col = 2 To rng.End(xlToRight).Column

        If Cells(rng.Row, col) <> 0 Then

            target.Range("E5").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Cells(rng.Row, col)
            target.Range("E5").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1) = account

        End If

    Next col

Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Getting Application defined or object defined error .

Comment: I have multiple values in Amount for each account

Comment: Which line gives error? Also I thought for each account there are multiple values and you want them listed, one on top of the other?

Comment: target.Range("E5").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = Cells(rng.Row, col)

Comment: But yes you are correct I have multiple account on Column A and each row has multiple amount

Comment: In this way we will have unique amount but they might have same account

Comment: Do you get any output or does the line throw an error straight away?

Comment: Hmmm. It worked for me on my machine. Is `target` set up correctly e.g. there is a worksheet called `updated`?. You may have to simplify the code to isolate the error...

Comment: Once it reaches to if loop and tries to put the value it errors  out.

Comment: I have updated the subroutine and question on this page as well.